# Django validation with ReactJS and Redux Form

Tags: python, django, forms, reactjs, redux

Currently, I am working on a project that uses ReactJS, Redux, and Django. I have a ReduxForm for registration.

```
    <h3>Company's basic information</h3>
        <Field 
          // Redux form props
          name="name"
          component={renderTextField}
          label="Company's Name"

          // Custom props
          required={true}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Company's Name..."
          onBlur={this.handleFieldsChange.bind(this)}
        />
```

So a single field looks something like that.
When the form is submitted the information is sent over to Django to store. I am unsure of how validation works between these two.
What I am wanting to do is check if a company exists with that name.

```
Organization.objects.filter(company_name=name)
```

So I do this to and I am able to see if it exists.

If it does, then I want to make it known to the user that they cannot have the same name.
This is where I am unsure of how to make this work.
I did something like

```
raise ValidationError({'name': ["A company named '%s' already exists" % name,]})
```

However, this only make the form not submit. The validation error only appears in the log.

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Well you should have this same message in the content of your repsonse.

Comment: @Bestasttung Thank you. This actually did help point me in the right direction.

Comment: My pleasure ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it turns out that the problem was the location with the raise ValidationError. I was doing it in the Model in a save function. What I needed to do was move it to the Organization serializer.
Also, instead of just

```
raise ValidationError({'name': ["A company named '%s' already exists" % name,]})
```

I changed it to

```
raise serializers.ValidationError({'name': "A company named '%s' already exists" % name })
```

Now it would seem when there is a organization that already exists with this name, it appears under the field with this message.